# Azure Service Bus - push to HTTP endpoint

Tags: azure

I'm looking for an Azure recipe whereby a Service Bus results in a HTTP endpoint being called to push the message there.  Effectively a web hook mechanism.

On AWS this is possible with SNS I believe.. I've looked at the Notification Hubs, but they seem geared only to mobile platforms.  Within the main subscription APIs I haven't stumbled across anything that can do that.

Is there a combination of services/configurations which will do this?

The use case is to integrate old and new systems; the new system will post messages to a queue, and the old system would have a HTTP endpoint invoked - so we can just update the existing web app rather than develop a new Windows Service to pull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service Bus by itself will not push anything anywhere, except for Notification Hubs as you mentioned. But those are really only for mobile push notifications.

One option would be to use a Service Bus Queue or Event Hub in combination with a Function App. The Function could be created with the trigger template for Queue or Event Hub. The Function could then call your WebHook or do any other things you want it to do.